# Unity3D error Fix

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working in Unity 3d, once I opened the program, an error faced me.

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/QCARWrapper.dll', expected 64 bit architecture (IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64), but was IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386.
```

what is the solution for this error?

Comment: I'm guessing that DLL file is for an AMD 64 bit architecture, but you've got an Intel I3 32-bit architecture.

Comment: how can I solve it? @9Deuce

Comment: Are you using Vuforia on this project at all?

Comment: Probably look up the 32-bit DLL of the QCARWrapper online

Comment: Afaik, Vuforia does not support Unity 64 bit at the moment. You need to download Unity 32-bit if you want to use it on Editor. Running on device is ok. Also make sure you have the latest Unity for Vuforia to work probably.

Comment: Thank you @NguyễnTrườngChung